# change the selected option color (while its selected)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When an option is selected (regardless of its color or background color), it's background will be set to blue and the font color to white. How to change these behaviors? Say I want to set the font color to red, while an option is selected.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you mean by "option" without seeing your HTML! Are these links? If so, use CSS to style your a:active { ... } and a:visited { ... } colors. If you mean actual `<option>` tags in a <select> dropdown, then you can't just "override" the color - it's controlled by the browser. You would need to fake a select element of your own, or use something like jQuery UI to do it for you.

Comment: You can't, select elements aren't very styleable and your best bet would be to use a plugin that recreates the select with a styled list or something similar.

Comment: Don't know what you're really asking, but this may help: http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/eHLwc/ (but really *do* test this in many browsers, this can be glitchy).

Comment: To elaborate a bit more, the browser will often use the underlying operating system to style dropdown boxes. This is why you can't reliably style a select box with CSS. Last I checked Chrome and Safari were particularly unreliable. As Adeneo said, a totally custom plug in solution that simulates a dropdown is the only way to consistently style a dropdown.

Comment: My issue is with chrome. when select an option and blur, the selected TEXT is somehow not visible!

Answer (score 1):

**[updated]**

As far as I know, you cannot do that because it is not rendered in the browser. this is rendered by the OS. so if you want that badly, build your own or use other libraries' menus like Jquery UI's ..

[**Read this**](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/select)

Example (using jquery ui set your css to this while using menus):

```
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus{
    color:red;
    background-color:lime;
    background-image:none;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CME64/RDfjw/)**

Or just customize the library from **[HERE](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/)** (preferable)

check **[THIS](http://jqueryui.com/menu/)** to know how to use Jquery ui menus

Comment: Thanks for that but I need to do this on the current select option and dont want to build my own

Comment: you're welcome ,,, then wait for the operating system designers to allow you to do that, I would say 10 years from now ,, nah maybe never